# How to redirect to a new url on the basis of a parameter in Spring

Tags: spring, redirect

My RequestMapping & ResponseBody is like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/someURL", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView getDetails(
        @RequestParam(value = "param1", required = false) String param1,
        @RequestParam(value = "param2", required = false) String param2,
 {
```

Now on the basis of param1, I want to redirect to a particular URL. 
Eg. Right now after processing, my page is going to

```
http://parent-domain/someURL?param1=...param2=...
```

But what I want is to completely change the parent domain like this

```
http://some-other-domain/someURL?param1=...param2=...
```

Comment: That little thing is call `if`... `if (param1.equals(whatever))` redirect to the url .

Comment: can you please tell, how to redirect. I am pretty new to spring.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/someURL", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public ModelAndView getDetails(@RequestParam(value = "param1", required = false) String param1,
                                   @RequestParam(value = "param2", required = false) String param2) {
        if (param1.equals("a"))
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:somotherurl"); 
        else
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:http://google.com");
    }
```

if param1 is a then it will go to someotherurl in parent else it will redirect to google.com